# git config alias adding slashes

Tags: bash, git

I'm creating an install script for a load aliases and git config is not playing nice with them

Here is the command in the shell script

```
git config --global alias.sync-fork '"!f() { oldhash="$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)"; (git fetch --all && git stash --include-untracked) && ( (git checkout "$(git default-branch)" && git pull && git merge upstream/"$(git default-branch)" && git push && git checkout -); [ "$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)" != "$oldhash" ] || git stash pop) }; f"'
```

When I run it and look in the `~/.gitconfig` file, I see `"\"` everywhere and it doesn't work. Using echo, I can see the string I want. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Why did you add `"`s inside the `'`s?

Comment: ...mind, I'd argue that a much better approach is to not try to put this much logic in an alias at all, and instead write it to a script; make the alias call the script and there you are, no worrying about how to escape your shell function to live inside a string in the first place.

Comment: ...also, why this many subshells? What benefit do you get from `( a && b ) && ( c )` instead of `a && b && c`?

Comment: Also, instead of `a && b && c`, think about `a || return; b || return; c || return` -- simpler logic to think about if you're explicit about "if this fails, we want to bail out".

Comment: To be clear, though, the extra slashes in `.gitconfig` are normal and expected; that's a normal part of how one expresses literal double quotes in that config file.

Comment: I would suggest to put such a sequence of actions in a script ...

Comment: @LeGEC doesn’t answer the question. I need these commands to be added to git alias. The example will already be contained within a script.

Comment: To mention one extra step down the script road : if any executable or script named `git-<blah>` is accessible from your PATH, you can then invoke it by running `git <blah>`, as if `<blah>` was a git command or an alias. This allows you to avoid a lot of hair pulling considerations w.r.t to sticking with a pure alias.

Comment: that being said : if you have an ulterior motive to set an alias, you should definitely go that way. CherlesDuffy's answer is a very good one.

Comment: Hmmm you raise a good point. I'll consider that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *most immediate* problem is that you have too many quotes; `'"..."'` should just be `'...'` without the `"`s inside. However, I can't guarantee that you won't have more issues after you fix that one.

Instead of trying to escape your shell function by hand, have the shell itself do it for you using `declare -f` to serialize your function.

```
f() {
  oldhash="$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)"
  (git fetch --all &&
   git stash --include-untracked
  ) && (
   (git checkout "$(git default-branch)" &&
    git pull &&
    git merge upstream/"$(git default-branch)" &&
    git push &&
    git checkout -)
   [ "$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)" != "$oldhash" ] || git stash pop)
}
git config --global alias.sync-fork '!'"$(declare -f f); f"
```

This *does* mean git will add some extra escapes to fit the function into proper config-file form, but when you use `declare -f` the output is guaranteed to be well-formed (at least if your `/bin/sh` is provided by bash).